# Problems with vue.js content rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've just learning Vue.js and I'm getting stuck with some problems with its rendering.
Let's say I have the following lines of code:

**index.html**

```
<div id="header">
  <h5>{{pageName}}</h5>
  <p>{{pageSubtitle}}</p>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var header = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
  data: {
    pageName: 'CuteCat',
    pageSubtitle: 'World of cats'
  }
});
```

When I load the page, the `CuteCat` and `World of cats` is shown perfectly but when I view source, this is what I get:

```
<div id="header">
  <h5>{{pageName}}</h5>
  <p>{{pageSubtitle}}</p>
</div>
```

What can I do to replace the mustaches brackets in the view source with its declared value like this?

```
<div id="header">
  <h5>CuteCat</h5>
  <p>World of cats</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the dev tools ("Inspect element") where the elements show their current values. "View source" shows the raw HTML without Vue processing, in order to modify that you would need to pre-render your application, and it's pretty tedious if it's just for that. | Also, you have Vue-devtools that integrate with the browser ones: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Answer (score 1):

Just as @yuriy636 is telling you, this is not an error by any means.

Vue is a JavaScript UI framework, making its magic in the client (i.e. in the browser). In the source view you see what's been loaded from the server and what you see is exactly that.

If you disable JavaScript for a session and reload your app, the double mustaches will be visible. Because they are replaced by Vue when JS is on.

Edit: In the DOM, however everything is normal after Vue rendering, just as you would expect it.